# How can I filter entries in dynamodb which has time_stamp more than 1 day?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a lambda function which queries dynamoDb table userDetailTable, and I want to filter only the entries whose timestamp(recorded in ms) has exceeded 1 day (86400000 ms) when subtracted from (new Date.getTime()). Can anyone suggest me the way for doing it in the right way ?

Dynamo Table has GSIndex as `user_status` which has value 'active' for all the entries and epoch_timestamp(timestamp in ms) as attribute used for filter expression.
In Lambda I am checking `epoch_timestamp` and trying to subtract epoch_timestamp with (new Date.getTime()) in the query, which I am not sure is even possible. Below is the code which has my query.

```
function getUserDetails(callback){
  var params = {
    TableName: 'userDetailTable',
    IndexName: 'user_status-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'user_status = :user_status',
    FilterExpression: `expiration_time - ${new Date().getTime()} > :time_difference`, 
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
      ':user_status': 'active',
      ':time_difference': '86400000' // 1 day in ms  
    } 
  };
  docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      callback(err, null)
    } else{
      callback(null, data)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rewrite of your code:

```
function getUserDetails(callback){
    var params = {
        TableName: 'userDetailTable',
        IndexName: 'user_status-index',
        KeyConditionExpression: 'user_status = :user_status',
        FilterExpression: 'epoch_timestamp > :time_threshold_ms', 
        ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
            ':user_status': 'active',
            ':time_threshold_ms': Date.now() - 86400000
        } 
    };
    docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            callback(err, null)
        } else{
            callback(null, data)
        }
    })
}
```

Specifically, in the `FilteExpression` you cannot compute any date. Instead you should compare the item's `epoch_timestamp` attribute with `time_threshold_ms` which you compute once (for all items inspected by the query) at `ExpressionAttributeValues`

Please note though that you are can make this more efficient if you define a GSI which uses `epoch_timestamp` as its *sort key* (`user_status` can remain the partition key). Then, instead of placing the condition in the `FilterExpression` you will need to move it into `KeyConditionExpression`.

Also, when you use a `FilterExpression` you need to check the `LastEvaluatedKey` of the response. If it is not empty you need to issue a followup query with `LastEvaluatedKey` copied into the request's `ExclusiveStartKey`. Why? due to filtering it is possible that you will get no results from the "chunk" (or "page") examined by DDB. DDB only examines a single "chunck" at each query invocation. Issuing a followup query with `ExclusiveStartKey` will tell DDB to inspect the next "chunk".

(see https://dzone.com/articles/query-dynamodb-items-withnodejs for further details on that)

Alternatively, if you do not use filtering you are advised to use pass a `Limit` value in the request to tell DDB to stop after the desired number of items. However, if you do use filtering *do not pass a `Limit` value* as it will reduce the size of the "chunk" and you will need to do many more followup queries until you get your data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform a calculation in the filter expression but you can calculate it outside and use the result with a new inequality.

I think you are looking for items expiring after one day from now.
Something like

```
FilterExpression: 'expiration_time > :max_time',
ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
  ':user_status': 'active',
  ':max_time': new Date().getTime() + 86400000 // 1 day in ms // i.e. one day from now.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I was looking new Date().getTime() - 86400000. But anyways, your reply was insightful